# JavaScript strting to date type convert DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, html, json, datetime, type-conversion

I've a JSON response and returns me String "30-05-2020 12:02:29" . In javascript how can i make this string to convert datetime ?

Comment: You have a couple options:

1. Use the `Date` class. Something like `var d = new Date(string_val);`

2. Use moment.js. Since you're returning a format somewhat abnormal, you can use that to specify the contents.

Comment: We are of course assuming you actually meant JavaScript, as you typed in the title and in the question text, not Java, as you tagged the question. Java != JavaScript, and it would behoove you to learn the name of the language you're writing code in.

Comment: Although if the JSON response comes from JAVA, perhaps it is the server response that is worth changing